# FatFractal Deployment Error 400: User does not have permission to deploy

Tags: web-applications, custom-backend

I am attempting to deploy my web application to the FatFractal Cloud server, and the

`ffef deployFFFabric`

command-line tool is returning the following error:

`Deployment response code : 400`

`Failed to deploy : reason [400: ffPermissions: User mv0KsSPKJe4gdAhbmxD3w6 does
not have permission to deploy Application with context: ToDos to Domain: testing.]`

When I log in to the FatFractal Console, my `ToDos` application is listed as belonging to my `testing` subdomain, so I am sure that they are both registered under my FatFractal user account. In addition, I am able to successfully deploy this application on my localhost using `ffef deploylocal`.

Any ideas as to why this error may be occurring and/or what steps I could take to troubleshoot the cause?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like your PEM got corrupted somehow. Try deleting it:

```
rm /install/path/FatFractal_Runtime/conf/.pem
```

Now, the next time you run `ffef deployFFFabric`, it will prompt you for your FatFractal login information again and regenerate the PEM.